# Delete statement with OUTPUT clause in azure sql

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using the OUTPUT clause of a DELETE statement to insert into an archive table.

This code is working without issue on my local database. However I get an error when running on an Azure database because the column values are null.

Why would this behave differently on Azure?

This code:

```
DECLARE @courseId uniqueidentifier
SET @courseId = 'c7f5a926-e77a-4465-9120-38da284ed7d5'

DECLARE @courseCode nvarchar(max)
SELECT @courseCode = CourseCode FROM Courses WHERE CourseId = @courseId

SELECT @courseId
SELECT @courseCode

-- Courses
DELETE Courses
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO Archived_Courses
WHERE CourseId = @courseId
```

Returns this error:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 16 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'CourseName', table     '...dbo.Archived_Courses'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You've not shown us the table definitions - have you checked them yourself? Also, we don't have any data - are you sure you're working with identical table definitions *and* similar enough data between your local machine and Azure?

Comment: Will double check this later. Assuming that Azure SQL supports a delete statement with output clause could a different clustered index on the tables cause this behaviour?

Comment: You were correct - there is a long list of columns and two of the columns had their positions switched. This raises a further question about whether to specify column names in the OUTPUT DELETED.* clause - any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'd say that you should always specify a column list outside of two circumstances - when you're prototyping and when you're specifying an `EXISTS()` subquery. Columns should be referenced by name rather than (expected) ordinal position.

Comment: By specifying a column list in OUTPUT DELETED is there not the possibility of data loss if a column is added to the table in future but mistakenly the DELETE statement is not updated? It would be hard to detect this.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand even wrote a article titled [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). And it even includes the very error that brought you here in the first place (column order changed)

Comment: I'm not defending the use of Select * in general, but it seems there may be a case for its defense here. If a column is added to the table being archived but the archive table schema is not updated with the new column, won't this be caught when attempting to insert into the archive table? Admittedly they are still a host of other pitfalls here though...

Comment: I'm not the SQL police. If you think it's of value then use it. The real danger though is that multiple changes will end up swapping columns. I.e. imagine a profit and loss ledger that, for whatever reason, ends up removing the loss column temporarily and then reintroducing it. Now you're recording things exactly backwards, if you're using positional expectations. And `select *` doesn't "warn" you.

Comment: Thanks for your input - it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a repor, who actually worked pretty well on my SQL Azure Database :
Assuming you have something like that :

```
Create Table Courses
(
    CourseId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newid(),
    CourseCode nvarchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT newid(),
    CourseDescription nvarchar(MAX) NULL
)  

Create Table Archived_Courses
(
    CourseId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    CourseCode nvarchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    CourseDescription nvarchar(MAX) NULL
)
```

And here is your solution, that worked for me (only difference, i get the unique identiefier with a simple Select on the course code)

```
Insert into Courses (CourseCode, CourseDescription) values ('MOD01', 'Module 1 description');

DECLARE @courseId uniqueidentifier
Select @courseId = CourseId from Courses where CourseCode = 'MOD01'

DECLARE @courseCode nvarchar(max)
SELECT @courseCode = CourseCode FROM Courses WHERE CourseId = @courseId

SELECT @courseId
SELECT @courseCode

-- Courses
DELETE Courses
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO Archived_Courses
WHERE CourseId = @courseId
```

Are you sure, you don't have any default value generated on Insert in your On Premise database, that you don't have on your Azure SQL Database ?

Sébastien

Comment: The problem was due to column order being switched for two columns. Thanks for confirming that the OUTPUT clause was working as expected on Azure.

Comment: (I'm not sure your example code above should be assigning a newid() to the Courses.CourseCode column)